# Cannot POST in angular 6

Tags: angular, api, typescript, angular6

I am getting an uncertain issues with angular 6 while submitting login form.

I have setup it all in localhost and i have saved the api files in localhost root and inside the angular project folder but it does not work for anyone. Here the the API directory  /api/auth.php

I am getting the error in console -> network tab i.e **Cannot POST  /api/auth.php**

Below is my **auth.service.ts** files.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError }  from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient
  ) { }
  getUsersDetail(userName, userPassword){
    return this.http.post('/api/auth.php', {
      userName,
      userPassword
    }, {responseType: 'text'}).pipe(
      map(data => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      }),
      catchError(error =>{
        return throwError("Something webt wrong"+JSON.stringify(error));
      })
    ).subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data, 'is what we got from server');
    });
  }
}
```

Below is my **login.component.html** files.

```
<form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
    <div><input type="text" name="loginName" id="userName"></div>
    <div><input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="userPassword"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Below is my **login.component.ts** files.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Auth:AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginUser(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Here we go '+event);
    const userName     = event.target.querySelector('#userName').value;
    const userPassword = event.target.querySelector('#userPassword').value;
    console.log('Credentials '+userName+' = '+userPassword);
    this.Auth.getUsersDetail(userName, userPassword);

  }

}
```

Note : Its working fine when i get the login form data inside login.component.ts but i am not able to find the API file its returing 404 i think so can anyone suggest where i should need to place the API folder where it will work my localhost URL is something like this `http://localhost:4200/login`

Comment: try to add the full request path and not just relative, for example, http://localhost:3000/api/auth.php

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't your `map` call return something, such as `JSON.stringify(data)`?

Comment: Its the http://localhost:4200/ base URL and i have because in XAMPP  localhost working without socket 4200 so my question is where should i need to put the API folder for php that will interact with database.
1) Should i need to save it in root of XAMPP ?
2) Or inside the project my project directory is root E:\Xampp\htdocs\ng-auth

Comment: In XAMPP you still get a url, you can get a custom url.. You have to put the full path to HTTP request in the call. In your code example, it is not a full path.

Answer (score 2):

Usually We put the HOST of back end API in a entry of enviroment file .. so you can easly change different stage (test / qa/ stanging / prod) from you front end run locally .. without having to refactor your Services:

something like:

enviroment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL: 'http://localhost:1048/api/'
};
```

then for example enviroment.staging.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  API_URL: 'http://staging.mysite.com/api/'

};
```

and then in your services:
//import your enviroment

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

getUsersDetail(userName, userPassword){
    return this.http.post(environment.APIURL + '/api/auth.php', {
      userName,
      userPassword
    }, {responseType: 'text'}).pipe(
      map(data => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      }),
      catchError(error =>{
        return throwError("Something webt wrong"+JSON.stringify(error));
      })
    ).subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data, 'is what we got from server');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I needed to get a page with POST instead of GET.
My solution was put a rule on nginx that allow the request with POST

```
 location / {
            ...
            error_page 405 =200 $uri;
        }
```

check this for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405